# #DIV/0! error in uncompleted spreadsheet

Tags: excel-formula

=AVERAGE(D7:D8) is the formula, I have a number of variations of this but the spreadsheet will be filled in as and when and need the fields not to show an error but to show the value if one or more of the fields are filled.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap in IFERROR():

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(D7:D8),"")
```

You can replace the `""` with `0` if that is what you want to show instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, just could get my head round it